# One page responsive menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, navigation, responsive

Have a one page responsive dropdown menu built using ul li a and when the hamburger is clicked to close it on mobile it will hide the ul correctly. Problem is when I resize to view the desktop version and select a menu item that ul is hidden as well. I can't figure out how to just target the ul for the mobile version only...here is the js

**Menu JS**

```
    (function($) {
      $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
        var cssmenu = $(this),
          settings = $.extend({
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
          }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          $(this).find(".button-mobile").on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
              mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
            } else {
              mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });
          cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
              } else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
              }
            });
          };
          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
          if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
          resizeFix = function() {
            var mediasize = 960;
            if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
              cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
            if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
              cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            }
          };
          resizeFix();
          return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);

    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
          format: "multitoggle"
        });
        $("#cssmenu ul li a").on('click','li', function() {
           $(".button-mobile").removeClass('menu-opened');
      //   $(this).next('ul').show();
        });
    });
  })(jQuery);
```

**HTML**

```
    <header>
        <div class="container logo-nav">
            <div class="sixteen columns">
                <div class="logo"></div>
                <nav id="cssmenu">
                    <div class="button-mobile"></div>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#about" class="smoothScroll">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#services" class="smoothScroll">SERVICES</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#research-media" class="smoothScroll">RESEARCH-MEDIA</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#creative" class="smoothScroll">CREATIVE</a></li>
                        <li class="buttonfill"><a href="#contact" class="smoothScroll">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
          </div>
      </div>
        <hr>
    </header><!--  End Header -->
```

I need to either ad an id or class via js to that ul that will only be applied when the browser is at 960 which is showing the mobile version of the nav but I'm not sure how to configure the code.

Comment: use css @media query to find the screen size. ex: @media(max-width:560px) { /* PLACE CSS FOR MOBILE VERSION */ }

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using:

```
$("#cssmenu ul").css('display', '');
```